# How to set a limit to the number of elements that appear on a matplotlib bar chart's x-axis?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

[image: db]

I have to find the 5 trips with the longer duration, but matplotlib gives me a very ugly graph as there are a lot of entries on the db. Can I somehow set a limit on the quantity of bars that the chart will show? I know it'll be more than 1000 bars, but I want matplotlib to only show me the first like 10.

I have this code, but doesn't do the work as required. It gives me an unreadable chart with every single `trips_duration` value.

```
trips_duration = trips_copy.copy()
trips_duration.duration.value_counts().plot(kind='bar' ,title='longest trips')
```

[image: trip durations]

Comment: Do you just want the first ten entries, or do you want to group values into ten bars? If the latter, use a histogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest:

`trips_duration.duration.nlargest(n=10).plot(kind='bar' ,title='longest trips')`

Note that the `keep=` argument of [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) allows you to decide how to break ties, if that matters for your use case.

If you need more options for how to sort, you could use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values) and then subset the top ten values:

`trips_duration.duration.sort_values(ascending=False)[:10].plot(kind='bar' ,title='longest trips')`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude <3

Comment: For sure, @MrAlien.  Could you mark this answer as accepted?